# Java - handling exceptions higher in call stack?

Tags: java, exception

If the result of `foo()` is passed to `bar()` and `bar()` has a mechanism for handling exceptions, why does this fail to compile (unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown)?

```
public class Foobar {
  public static int foo() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(bar(foo()));
  }

  public static int bar(int x) {
    try {
      return x;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when foo() throws the exception he is not inside the bar code block yet. It will first execute foo() then pass the return to bar()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo()` is "executed" in the `main` method not in the `bar` method, then return of `foo()` is passed to `bar()`.

`foo` is called before `bar()` call to calculate the int to pass to `bar` so the exception will be propagated to `main` not `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the result of `foo()` is used as a parameter to `bar(..)`, it has to be calculated before `bar` can be called. But before the result of `foo` can be established an exception is thrown, resulting in abnormal termination and no further code execution (except for finally blocks and until the exception is caught). This would all be different if `foo` would **return** the exception instead of throwing it.